# Run aarch64 Docker image in GitHub x86 container workflow

Tags: docker, github-actions, arm64, multiplatform, docker-buildkit

I'm testing a GitHub workflow that checks if the code compiles on arm64, using a Linux/aarch64 Docker container for the build. I'm aware GitHub containers are x86 only, however I'd like to know if it is possible to execute multi-arch images in docker on GitHub managed workflows.

- I've built an image with 'docker buildx' set up for linux/amd64, linux/arm64 as per https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-arch-images/
- the packaged image manifest shows it is multi-arch and testing manually it works.

### Details

- image https://github.com/donsbot/hsthrift/pkgs/container/hsthrift%2Fci-base/13306041?tag=ghcup-arm64v8
- workflow to boot this https://github.com/facebookincubator/hsthrift/actions/runs/1706096700/workflow

On GitHub the CI job is executed and the container initializes ok:https://github.com/facebookincubator/hsthrift/runs/4835956150?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:14

```
  /usr/bin/docker pull ghcr.io/donsbot/hsthrift/ci-base:ghcup-arm64v8
  ghcup-arm64v8: Pulling from donsbot/hsthrift/ci-base
...
  Digest: sha256:4c09341793d78efb74ad751b55152637d00b6297049458923825368fffb5485d
  Status: Downloaded newer image for ghcr.io/donsbot/hsthrift/ci-base:ghcup-arm64v8
  ghcr.io/donsbot/hsthrift/ci-base:ghcup-arm64v8

  /usr/bin/docker create .. --cpus 2 ... --entrypoint "tail" ghcr.io/donsbot/hsthrift/ci-base:ghcup-arm64v8 "-f" "/dev/null"
  a63c28c54f278781f85a4ca85e3b1f5c3dd7c0d6b125fbcfd0e1d2f57ad0b0ef

  /usr/bin/docker start a63c28c54f278781f85a4ca85e3b1f5c3dd7c0d6b125fbcfd0e1d2f57ad0b0ef
  a63c28c54f278781f85a4ca85e3b1f5c3dd7c0d6b125fbcfd0e1d2f57ad0b0ef

  /usr/bin/docker ps --all --filter id=a63c28c54f278781f85a4ca85e3b1f5c3dd7c0d6b125fbcfd0e1d2f57ad0b0ef --filter status=running --no-trunc --format "{{.ID}} {{.Status}}"
  a63c28c54f278781f85a4ca85e3b1f5c3dd7c0d6b125fbcfd0e1d2f57ad0b0ef Up Less than a second

  /usr/bin/docker inspect --format "{{range .Config.Env}}{{println .}}{{end}}" a63c28c54f278781f85a4ca85e3b1f5c3dd7c0d6b125fbcfd0e1d2f57ad0b0ef
  CI=true
  HOME=/github/home
  GITHUB_ACTIONS=true
  PATH=/root/.ghcup/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
  TZ=Europe/London
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
```

So that all looks fine and happy. But the job fails on the first exec step as the VM is not running.

> Error response from daemon: Container a63c28c54f278781f85a4ca85e3b1f5c3dd7c0d6b125fbcfd0e1d2f57ad0b0ef is not running

This works successfully locally on various hosts.

### Question

- how can I debug what's happening to the container here?
- are multi-arch images generally supported on x86 Docker containers on GitHub? (other examples)

### Related work

- https://github.community/t/ask-about-github-hosted-runners-arm64-platform-support/167483/3
- https://github.com/uraimo/run-on-arch-action

Answer (score 1):

This missing piece is multi-arch support in the standard GitHub 'container' docker engine.

Instead of using the 'container' method, we can use invoke the cross-compile steps in a fresh docker container manually. This is automated by the run-on-arch-action, which takes care of getting qemu and docker into the right state.

> docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --reset -p yes

https://github.com/uraimo/run-on-arch-action

The yml file for building on non-x86 now looks like:

```
 build-on-aarch64:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: ci (arm64)
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Build in arm64 container
        uses: uraimo/run-on-arch-action@v2.1.1
        with:
          arch: aarch64
          distro: ubuntu20.04
          # Install deps into the container. With the token, the container will be cached
          # The image is cached publically like a package
          githubToken: ${{ github.token }}
          install: |
             .. install packages for the arm container (e.g. Dockerfile steps)
          run: |
             .. run build steps on the container
```

This action essentially builds the Docker image for us, with qemu set up, takes care of caching it, and runs it with the right emulation for the GitHub runner hosts.